# how to focus the clicked bar in C3.js bar graph?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I have this code which makes a graph using c3.js : https://jsfiddle.net/1bxe2scd/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dsnap - Charts</title>
  <!-- Load c3.css -->
  <link href="c3/c3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  <!-- Load d3.js and c3.js -->
  <script src="d3/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="c3/c3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chart" style="width:480px;height:400px"></div>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script>

  var chart = c3.generate({

                  bar: {
                      width: 15
                  },
                  padding: {
                      left: 60
                  },
                  data: {
                      x: 'Date',
                      columns:
                          [
                        ['Date', '2011-02','2013-01','2013-02','2013-03','2013-04','2013-05','2013-06','2013-07','2013-08','2013-09','2013-10','2013-11','2013-12','2014-01','2014-02'],
                        ['value', 777,53,165,269,344,376,410,421,405,376,359,392,433,455,978]
                        ],

                      type: 'bar',
                      onclick: function(e) { console.log(e.x);}


                  },
                  axis: {
                      rotated: true,
                      x: {
                          type: 'category'
                      }
                  },
                  tooltip: {
                      grouped: false
                  },
                  legend: {
                      show: false
                  }
              });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the bar on which the user clicks to be focused and the rest of the bar should become faded, how can I achieve that?

How can I get the Y value of the clicked bar(eg: 2011-02 etc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this for highlighting the bar:

```
onclick: function(e) {
  //make all the bar opacity 0.1
    d3.selectAll(".c3-shape").style("opacity",0.1);
  var k = ".c3-shape-"+ e.index;
  //make the clicked bar opacity 1
  d3.selectAll(k).style("opacity",1)
}
```

Working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/8upy9byp/)

On clicking out side in the chart if you wish to bring back all the bars attach the click listener to the chart and on click make all bar's opacity 1:

```
d3.selectAll("#chart").on("click", function(d) {
  //reset all the bars
  d3.selectAll(".c3-shape").style("opacity", 1);
})
```

Working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/35qahpsr/1/)

**EDIT**

So now since you have two charts specify the id also to make it specific to the chart note the id in the selector: (#chart/#chart1):

```
d3.selectAll("#chart1").on("click", function(d) {
  //reset all the bars for chart1
  d3.selectAll("#chart1 .c3-shape").style("opacity", 1);
})

d3.selectAll("#chart").on("click", function(d) {
  //reset all the bars for chart
  d3.selectAll("#chart .c3-shape").style("opacity", 1);
})
```

On click for chart1 bar will look like this:

```
onclick: function(e) {
      //make all the bar opacity 0.1 for chart1
      d3.selectAll("#chart1 .c3-shape").style("opacity", 0.1);
      var k = "#chart1 .c3-shape-" + e.index;
      //make the clicked bar opacity 1
      d3.selectAll(k).style("opacity", 1)
      event.stopPropagation()
    }
```

Working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/35qahpsr/3/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: The method you mentioned here wont work in case I have more than 1 bar graphs, how can I control fcous and defocus in that case, eg: https://jsfiddle.net/35qahpsr/2/?

Comment: You will need to fine tune the selector to include the specific chart like done here https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/35qahpsr/3/

Answer (score 0):

C3 has callbacks, for specifying what should happen when a click (or mouseover/mouseout) event occurs:

http://c3js.org/reference.html#data-onclick

It also has "APIs": functions you can call to basically act like the user made a selection or focused:

http://c3js.org/reference.html#api-focus

You could hook one of these up to trigger the other, like have the `onclick()` function call `focus()`.

But given what you're precisely looking for, the impediment would be that the `focus()` function doesn't accept the indices of individual bars on the graph. So it can only highlight an entire column/series of data at once, not individual bars. Here's the GitHub issue:

https://github.com/c3js/c3/issues/1389